# Healthcheck not working with exception handler .net core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-core-2.2

I want to use Healthcheck provided by .NetCore 2.2. Its pretty simple to configure.

Apart from using HealthCheck custom response, I am also using exceptionhandler to customize my exception in ErrorController.

The problem is Healthcheck not working. If any error throws from SQL connection, it goes to Error Controller instead of excecuting my custom response health check message. For simplification i just put only 2 line of code here. My actual code has lot of registration like swagger, autofac, fluentvalidation etc.,

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHealthChecks()
    .AddSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:defaultConnection"]);
}
```

Below is configure part of code, again for simplicity I put less code which is required for this issue.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var healthCheckOptions = new HealthCheckOptions();
            healthCheckOptions.ResultStatusCodes[HealthStatus.Unhealthy] = StatusCodes.Status503ServiceUnavailable;

            healthCheckOptions.ResponseWriter = async (context, report) =>
            {
                var problemDetails = new ProblemDetails
                {
                    Title = "ProviderUnavailable",
                    Status = (int)report.Status,
                    Detail = "Service is down",
                    Instance = context.TraceIdentifier
                };
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(problemDetails));
            };
            app.UseHealthChecks("/health", healthCheckOptions);
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/error-local-development");
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");
            }
            app.UseCors(x => x
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials());
}
```

and then the error throws in below code if i give wrong sql credentials.

```
public async Task<PerilsResponse> GetPerilRatingScoringAsync(PerilsRequest request)
        {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                await connection.OpenAsync();//Exception throws here.
             }
        }
```

**ErrorController.cs:**

```
[Route("/error-local-development")]
        [HttpGet]
        [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
        public IActionResult ErrorLocalDevelopment([FromServices] IHostingEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
        {                
            var feature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();
            var ex = feature?.Error;
            var isDev = webHostEnvironment.IsDevelopment();
            var problemDetails = new ProblemDetails
            {
                Status = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError,
                Instance = feature?.Path,
                Title = isDev ? $"{ex?.GetType().Name}: {ex?.Message}" : "An error occurred.",
                Detail = isDev ? ex?.StackTrace : null,
            };
            return StatusCode(problemDetails.Status.Value, problemDetails);
        }
```

The that exception is captured by middleware ErrorController. What I want is to return custom response which is written in the Configure portion of the code which is not getting called.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, healthcheck does NOT do anything other than return a healthcheck status from `/healthcheck` (configurable).  If your application throws *any* exception, that has absolutely nothing to do with the checkcheck middleware.

Comment: I cannot connect to database, so expected /healthcheck should return my custom data, since i have provided healthoptions. Even it is not returning healthy or unhealthy.

Comment: if your healthcheck throws an unhandled (no catch) exception, the `UseExceptionHandler` will catch it... hint hint, catch a `SqlException` in your healthcheck code.

Comment: the using() code throws SqlException: which is captured by UseExceptionHandler and the error controller codes gets executed.

Comment: That exactly how it's suppose to work.